# Searching multple mysql tables with limit using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and i had a function for searching multiple columns in mysql tables which is not working . i need to search with limit because i need the pagination with the search result .

For example say , 3 tables in my mysql database are `phones`, `articles`, `solutions` and the search string is `sony` . and i have `phones.name` and `articles.title` and `solutions.title` with the name `sony`.

my existing function is

```
public function get_search_res($search_str = null,$limit_start = null, $limit_end = null)
{


    $this->db->select('phones.name , phones.id');
    $this->db->select('solutions.title as s_title');
    $this->db->select('articles.title as a_title');
    $this->db->from('phones , soltions , articles');
    $this->db->like('phones.name', $search_str);
    $this->db->or_like('articles.title',$search_str);
    $this->db->or_like('solutions.title',$search_str);
    $this->db->limit($limit_start, $limit_end);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    $res = $q->result_array();

    return $res;
}
```

This function only gets the content form `solutions` table but could not get all content form another two tables with limit .

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is not possible.
Query with multiple tables is not used to do that.

You want to search into 3 tables, so you have to query each separately.

Get the COUNT results from each table to according your LIMIT in queries for result sets.